# Vaadin v23 -Pproduction BUILD FAILURE

Tags: build, vaadin23

I updated all architecture (Java17, Maven3, Spring 2.7/core5.3...) and Vaadin 23, but I can only run in development mode. I can no longer run -Pproduction. Build failure :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  33.260 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-31T11:35:42-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:flow-maven-plugin:23.1.6:build-frontend (default) on project template-module-app: Could not execute build-frontend goal: Error occured during goal execution: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Class.isInterface()" because the return value of "org.reflections.Reflections.forClass(String, java.lang.ClassLoader[])" is nullPlease run Maven with the -e switch (or Gradle with the --stacktrace switch), to learn the full stack trace. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:flow-maven-plugin:23.1.6:build-frontend (default) on project template-module-app: Could not execute build-frontend goal
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
```

I've tried everything:

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/tools/mpr/configuration/production-mode

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/tools/ce/going-to-production

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/production/troubleshooting

...

Comment: Is this the same issue you're having?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71868642/vaadin-maven-plugin-failed-to-build-frontend-after-updating-to-java-17

Comment: Let's say yes ! However, right after I opened this thread, it worked !!! There were a lot of cleans, rm -rf .m2/... It went back to Java11 and it still didn't work. But finally now it worked (using flow-server-production-mode) keeping everything up to date.